# How to install MySQL 5.7 using Ansible and Vagrant?

Tags: mysql, vagrant, ansible

I'm trying to install MySQL 5.7 automatically on an Ubuntu Trusty64 using Vagrant. This is how my install looks like:

```
- name: Install new APT package repository
  apt: deb=mysql-apt-config_0.7.2-1_all.deb
  sudo: yes
- name: Updating the cache
  apt: update_cache=yes
  sudo: yes
- name: Install mysql server
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items:
    - mysql-server
    - mysql-client
    - python-mysqldb
```

This installs MySQL 5.7 on the Vagrant instance but when I try to log in using `mysql -p -u root` it simply does not work; it seems not to have an empty password any more, I tried to check the output.

Is any way to get the password or may set it up during installation?

Comment: Would the `mysql_user` task help here? http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mysql_user_module.html

Answer (score 4):

Since version 5.7 MySQL is installed with not just empty password for root, but with authentication plugin auth_socket set for root account, so you can start `mysql` as user root without password, but the same command won't let you in when its started by another user. It's very nice, but surprising many of us. To achieve old style behaviour we are used to you need to change authentication plugin and set the password at once using command like this:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test';
```

I found it nicely explained here: [Change user password in MySQL 5.7 with “plugin: auth_socket”](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/) (and credits go there)

And here is my Ansible piece to do that:

```
  - name: Set MySQL root password
    command: /usr/bin/mysql -e "alter user 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourrootpassword';"
    ignore_errors: yes
    become: yes
```

I used `ignore_errors` to avoid stopping my playbook when it's run again - this command won't work after setting the password.

Comment: I've read that you can do this with the ansible `debconf` module, but it doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 14.04 and MySQL 5.7 and ansible 2.3.0.0-1

Answer (score 0):

This is how I configure mysql after installation in vagrant:

```
- name: Configure mysql step 1
  shell: echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password vagrant | debconf-set-selections
  become: true

- name: Configure mysql step 2
  shell: echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password vagrant | debconf-set-selections
  become: true

- name: Create mysql client configuration file
  blockinfile:
    dest: ~/.my.cnf
    create: yes
    block: |
      [client]
      user=root
      password=vagrant
```

I can't remember how I reached to this, it's been quite a while. Probably some link and experiments. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I found interesting that with the user vagrant mysql -p -u root or simply mysql -u root does not work.... but if you do the same as root you have no password and you can start doing your thing....

Cheers!

Comment: Check under the root user's home directory for a `.my.cnf` file to see why this is the case. You might want to edit this answer to more thoroughly explain why this works and how you can continue with your Ansible role/play using that information to set the root user's credentials or create more users etc.